# App Engine Cron.yaml run multiple instances of a script

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

How can one run multiple instances of a Script Using Google App Engine's Cron system?

By default, it will run, then wait the specified interval before running again, which means that only one instance runs. What i am looking for is how one can get a script that takes 2+ minutes to run start a new instance every 30-60 seconds regardless of if it is running already or not, which does assume the script does not interfere with itself if multiple instances are running. this would effectively allow the script to deal with several times more information in the same period of time.

Edit, Completely reworded the question.

Comment: AND no i will not be adding more information about my situation, if i do, you will be trying to answer a question that was not asked.

Comment: how does it different that running it every 30 seconds?

Comment: because the script takes more than 30 seconds to execute, up to 1.5 minutes. that is why i need Instances of it, instead of the script itself. due to poorly implemented systems on the other end, it takes significant time to execute. by running multiple instances of the script, the lag in communications is happening multiple times instead of just once. the problem is that if they run at hte same time, they get the same list to deal with, and this is a massive database they are pulling from.

Comment: You can make the cron job execute a task. Also you can use synchronized keyword, for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working off Dave W. Smith's answer, The Line would be

```
every 1 minute from 00:00 to 23:59
```

Which means that it would create a new instance every minute, even if the script takes longer than a minute to run. It does seem that specifying seconds is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You only get resolution to the minute. To get finer-grained, you'll need instances that know whether they should handle the request from chron immediately, of if they'll have to sleep 30 seconds first. A 30 second sleep uses up half of the 60 second request deadline. Depending on the workload you expect to handle, this might require that you use Modules.

By the way, I'm not aware of any guarantee that a job scheduled for 01:00 will fire at *exactly* 01:00:00 (and not at, say, 01:00:03).

Answer (score 1):

Since the cron service doesn't allow intervals below 1 min you'd need to achieve staggering script launching in a different manner. 
One possibility would be to have a cron entry handler running every 2 mins which internally sleeps for 30 seconds (or as low as your "few seconds of each-other" requirements are) between triggering the respective script instance launches.

**Note:** the sleeps would probably burn into your Instance Hours usage. You *might* be able to incorporate the staggered triggering logic into some other long-living task you may have instead of simply sleeping.

To decouple the actual script execution from the cron handler (or the other long-living task) execution you could use dedicated task queues for each script instance, with queue handlers sharing the actual script code if needed. The actual triggering would be done by enqueueing tasks in the respective script instance queue. As a bonus you may further control each script instance executions by customizing the respective queue configuration.

**Note:** if your script execution time exceeds the 2 minutes cron period you may need to take extra precautions in the queue configurations as there can be extra delays (due to queueing) which could push lauching of the respective script instance closer to the next instance launch.